# SQL Server SELECT with READONLY clause

Tags: sql-server, readonly

I wanted to read some data from a table in the read-only mode.

Having worked on DB2 earlier, I got confused and tried to use the FOR READONLY clause with my SELECT statement :P

After tinkering with it, I realized the following statement works:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Users READONLY
```

It took less than half the time to run the query with the READONLY clause than without it.

So I decided to google for some documentation about the same, but I couldn't find any documentation of using READONLY with the SELECT clause.

Our DBA has asked us not to use the READONLY clause if there is no documentation, as it can get obsolete in the newer updates/ versions.

I'd appreciate if someone can point to some useful documentation and let me know if this can be safely used in SQL Server stored procs.

I am using SQL Server version 11.0.3000.0

Answer (score 14):

Old question, but it deserves a new answer in case someone thinks they've stumbled on a magic go-faster switch.

This has the same semantics as `SELECT * FROM dbo.Users PLEASE_BUFF_MY_PYLONS`, and `SELECT * FROM Users AS U`. It assigns the alias `READONLY` to the table `Users` and has *no effect whatsoever* on execution plans or query execution time on its own, and anyone stating otherwise better have some damn good evidence to back it up (as in, an execution plan that does *not* show `READONLY` is just an alias). `READONLY` *is* a T-SQL keyword, but only in the context of passing table variables to stored procedures. In the context of this query, it's just another identifier.

There are various reasons why a query can be slower in one case, faster in another (cached execution plans are one big reason); aliasing your table to the name `READONLY` is not one of them.

While there's no such thing as "readonly" mode for a query, there *is* such a thing as reading from a table without blocking writers by using [snapshot isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server). This is not a magic go-faster switch either, but it is useful in many OLTP workloads.

Comment: A minor addition: READONLY is not onl a T-SQL keyword, but seems to occur (at least) in ISO SQL:2016 too, c. f. https://github.com/ronsavage/SQL, file "sql-2016.ebnf".

Answer (score 4):

This is a sample script to highlight what the `READONLY` means in the context you used it:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT);
INSERT INTO @t(id)VALUES(1),(2),(3);

SELECT READONLY.id FROM @t READONLY;
```

Resulting in:

```
id
1
2
3
```

In other words, you assigned an alias named `READONLY` to the table `dbo.users` (in the sample, to the table variable `@t`).

I would advise against using this as an alias. It may not result in an error, but it can be used in another context in SQL Server (declaring a table valued parameter in a stored procedure). Perhaps `READONLY` should have been a reserved keyword for this reason, as it may be confusing to see this word used as a keyword in one case, and as a table alias in another.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, you do not need to include the FOR READ ONLY clause in a SELECT statement. SELECT is a read-only operation by definition, so the FOR READ ONLY clause is usually unnecessary. In certain circumstances, however, you must include the FOR READ ONLY keywords in a SELECT statement.

[see this article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls694.htm) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. This is the DB2 documentation. I am looking specifically for SQL Server documentation. Also, if there is not much difference why is the query considerably faster?

Comment: There is no documented READONLY table hint in SQL Server, so I think your DBA is wise to advise against using it.  Using undocumented features is dicey as patches, service pack, or version upgrades can break the code.  I can't explain why you see a performance difference since I see no differences in the query plan or locking (using a SQL trace).

Comment: The link you pasted seems to be broken. Might the following link be a valid replacement for the broken link?: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1062.htm

Answer (score -1):

**Updated link:**

The link in bumbumpaw's reply is no longer valid. I found this in the IBM Knowledge Center regarding the use of the "FOR READ ONLY" clause when querying against an Informix database.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1062.htm

As Jeroen Mostert points out, Microsoft SQL Server does not contain a "READONLY" clause, even though it is a reserved keyword. It does, however, have an option to set the database level to "READ_ONLY", which is outside the scope of this question.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Please do not post a new answer simply to update a link or confirm someone else's statement. You may update a broken link by **editing the post** or add additional information **as a comment**.

Answer (score -1):

See the HINTS you can use here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver16

The NOLOCK is the "READONLY" you are searching for

Comment: Definitely not. It's the exact opposite: `NOLOCK` means don't respect any locks. It will return even locked rows that haven't been committed yet